# configure IIS 7.0 meta database issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, metabase

I am using IIS 7.0 + Windows Server 2008. Anyone has experience to configure the Timer_MinBytesPerSecond configuration items -- either programmatically or manually is fine? I also want to know how to check the current values for Timer_MinBytesPerSecond configuration items (either programmatically or manually is fine)?

All I find is how to configure this item in IIS 6.0, and I also cannot find this item in applicationHost.config, so I donot know how to fix it.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to start is %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema.  The IIS_schema.xml file has the definition for *everything* in IIS (except for some extensions which are in other files in that folder).

The schema files shows the default, where it should be set in the config and sometimes the range.

The next place to check is the IIS reference guide.  Here's the page that has the MinBytesPerSecond: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/webLimits

You can set these using appcmd or editing applicationHost.config directly.  Make sure to take a backup before starting.  appcmd add backup 'backup before starting minbytespersecond'